# I'm getting this error "com.example.viewmodelfactory.MainModelFactory cannot be cast to androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel "

Tags: kotlin, viewmodelfactory

Anyone tell me how to pass a default value in **ViewModelFactory** from **MainActivity**. I'm getting error  `com.example.viewmodelfactory.MainModelFactory cannot be cast to androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel`

```
class MainModelFactory (val counter: Int): ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return MainModelFactory(counter) as T

}
```

This is my ViewModelClass

```
 class MainViewModel(val intiallizeCount: Int) :ViewModel () {   
 var count : Int = intiallizeCount

     fun Increment()
     {
         count++
     }
 }
```

I'm passing the default count value in MainActivity

```
mainViewModel=ViewModelProvider(this, MainModelFactory(10)).get(MainViewModel:: class.java)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewModelProvider.Factory returns as a ViewModel object i.e.

```
return MainViewModel(counter) as T
```